# EF core "cannot insert explicit value for identity column" when using BYTE as identity column type in Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am having trouble seeding data into a SQL database using EF Core during program startup.

I have an EF Core table defined like this:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "PoolStyles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<byte>(type: "tinyint", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1,1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256),
                Code = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(40)", maxLength: 40),
                Description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(MAX)", nullable: true),
                IsRestricted = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit"),
                Priority = table.Column<byte>(type: "tinyint", nullable: true, defaultValue: 0),
                Icon = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(200)", maxLength: 200, nullable: true),
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_PoolStyles", x => x.Id);
            });
```

and here is the matching entity class:

```
public class PoolStyle
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public bool IsRestricted { get; set; }
    public byte Priority { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

During the start up of my application I attempt to seed some data into my database like so:

```
        if (!context.PoolStyles.Any())
        {
            context.PoolStyles.Add(new PoolStyle { Code = "SRV", Description = "Survival Pool", Icon = "", IsRestricted = false, Name = "Survival" });
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

However I keep getting the following error:

> An error occurred while migrating or seeding the database.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'PoolStyles' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

The error is preceded by the SQL EF Core tries to run:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
> Failed executing DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 1) (DbType = Byte), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000),
> @p3='?' (Size = 4000), @p4='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p5='?' (Size =
> 4000), @p6='?' (Size = 1) (DbType = Byte)], CommandType='Text',
> CommandTimeout='30']
> SET NOCOUNT ON;
> INSERT INTO [PoolStyles] (**[Id]**, [Code], [Description], [Icon], [IsRestricted], [Name], **[Priority]**)
> VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6);

**PROBLEM**: you can see that EF Core is adding the `[Id]` and `[Priority]` columns to the executed SQL but those values ARE NOT included in the object that I try to pass to the `SaveChangesAsync()` function.

Also, I am not using annotations so can't use those to solve this problem, I "hand code" the migrations because of the complexity of what I need.

**QUESTION**: can someone help me figure out why EF Core is trying to add these values to the insert statement?

Comment: This may be due to the data type and convention checking? Try adding [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] to the Id field.

Comment: EF is assuming Id is an identity column by [convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in). The easiest solution is to rename the attribute in your class and use the [Column] tag to associate the attribute with the column in your table.

Comment: thanks both nicholas and steve, It ended up being a data type issue and your comments got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was using **byte** as the data type for the identity column.  I am not sure why as I know that I can manually create an identity column in sql server with type **byte**.  Something in EF Core is choking.

### THE SOLUTION:

I changed the identity column data type to **int** and the insert works properly with auto incrementing id values.

Maybe I missed something else but its working and these table will not have many records so I will just use **int** and continue on, haha.

Comment: I am facing this even if I have int type.